# Incorrect Syntax - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I am trying to update two fields in my table `tbl_prev_data` using subquery because I had to use the aggregate `SUM`. But I don't know why it says

> Incorrect Syntax near 't'`

where `t` is a temp variable that holds the results of the subquery. Am I missing something ? Below is my query.

```
UPDATE tbl_prev_data
SET Original_Value = t.Original_Value 
SET Pre_Val = t.PreWDV
FROM tbl_prev_data 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         Asset_Group_Code, 
         ISNULL(SUM(Original_Value),0) AS 'Original_Value', 
         ISNULL(SUM(Prev_Val),0) AS 'PreWDV' 
     FROM 
         tbl_Asset_Master 
     GROUP BY 
         Asset_Group_Code, DOP 
     HAVING 
         (YEAR(DOP) != YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH (DOP) > 3) t ON tbl_prev_data.Asset_Group_Code = t.Asset_Group_Code
```

Comment: There is a bracket missing after  AND MONTH (DOP) > 3) which starts before select

Comment: @Jens, thank you. I didn't really notice. This was a real life saver. Thanks :)

Comment: Since you're not using a condition on an **aggregated** column, you should use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `SET` only *once*:

```
UPDATE tbl_prev_data
    SET Original_Value = t.Original_Value, 
        Pre_Val = t.PreWDV
FROM tbl_prev_data INNER JOIN ...
```

Other than that you also need to remove the redundant left parenthesis from the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING (YEAR(DOP) != YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH (DOP) > 3
-------^
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but it still seems to show the same error.

Answer (score 1):

it seems a problem with closing bracket. 
`(SELECT Asset_Group_Code, ...` 
is not closed with `)` before *t*.